# Anchor links are not going to the expected place

Tags: html

I have a few anchor tags in my page which are linked to paragraph tags with in the page

```
            <a href="#Win">Win Summary</a>
            <a href="#Client">Client</a>
            <a href="#Overview">Project Overview</a>
```

also on top of my page I have two divs.

The issue is, when I click on the anchor tag, the content in the paragraph tag starts from the top of the page, which makes some of the text go behind the two div on the top of page.

Which is something I dont want that should happen.

I have created a sample page to explain my issue, the code is given below:

```
    <html>

<head>
<style> 
#masthead {
    background-color: #131623;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-top: 0 none;
    left: 0;
    min-width: 980px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#masthead {
    border-bottom: 0 none;
    border-top: 4px solid #171A23;
    left: 0;
    min-width: 980px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 900;
}
#masthead {
    border-bottom: medium none;
    border-top: 0 none;
    box-shadow: none;
    overflow: visible;
    position: fixed;
}
#masthead {
    background-color: #131623;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-top: 1px solid #666666;
    left: 0;
    min-width: 980px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 900;
}

div, p, span, a, li, strong {
    font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
}

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, li, fieldset, form, label, legend {
    border: 0 none;
    font-size: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0 none;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="masthead">
  <div id="universal-nav" style="height:40px; background-color:#eaeaea;" >

  </div>
  <div class="menu-subtabs" style="height:30px; background-color:#fafafa;"">
        <h2>SalesOne</h2>

  </div>
</div>
</br></br></br></br></br>
<table border="0" summary="Content Block">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p xmlns="">
                <a href="#Win">Win Summary</a>
                <br/>
                <a href="#Client">Client</a>
                <br/>
                <a href="#Overview">Project Overview</a>
                <br/>
            </p>
            <p xmlns="" id="Win">
                <strong>
                    <font color="#008000">Win Summary</font>
                </strong>
            </p>
            <p xmlns="">
                Located in Norway, Yara International ASA is the world&#153;s leading chemical company that converts energy, natural minerals and nitrogen from the air into essential products for farmers and industrial customers. Through their environmental and industrial products, they help safeguard air and water quality and preserve food quality.Located in Norway, Yara International ASA is the world&#153;s leading chemical company that converts energy, natural minerals and nitrogen from the air into essential products for farmers and industrial customers. Through their environmental and industrial products, they help safeguard air and water quality and preserve food quality.Located in Norway, Yara International ASA is the world&#153;s leading chemical company that converts energy, natural minerals and nitrogen from the air into essential products for farmers and industrial customers. Through their environmental and industrial products, they help safeguard air and water quality and preserve food quality.Located in Norway, Yara International ASA is the world&#153;s leading chemical company that converts energy, natural minerals and nitrogen from the air into essential products for farmers and industrial customers. Through their environmental and industrial products, they help safeguard air and water quality and preserve food quality.Located in Norway, Yara International ASA is the world&#153;s leading chemical company that converts energy, natural minerals and nitrogen from the air into essential products for farmers and industrial customers. Through their environmental and industrial products, they help safeguard air and water quality and preserve food quality.Located in Norway, Yara International ASA is the world&#153;s leading chemical company that converts energy, natural minerals and nitrogen from the air into essential products for farmers and industrial customers. Through their environmental and industrial products, they help safeguard air and water quality and preserve food quality.Located in Norway, Yara International ASA is the world&#153;s leading chemical company that converts energy, natural minerals and nitrogen from the air into essential products for farmers and industrial customers. Through their environmental and industrial products, they help safeguard air and water quality and preserve food quality.Located in Norway, Yara International ASA is the world&#153;s leading chemical company that converts energy, natural minerals and nitrogen from the air into essential products for farmers and industrial customers. Through their environmental and industrial products, they help safeguard air and water quality and preserve food quality.Located in Norway, Yara International ASA is the world&#153;s leading chemical company that converts energy, natural minerals and nitrogen from the air into essential products for farmers and industrial customers. Through their environmental and industrial products, they help safeguard air and water quality and preserve food quality.Located in Norway, Yara International ASA is the world&#153;s leading chemical company that converts energy, natural minerals and nitrogen from the air into essential products for farmers and industrial customers. Through their environmental and industrial products, they help safeguard air and water quality and preserve food quality.Located in Norway, Yara International ASA is the world&#153;s leading chemical company that converts energy, natural minerals and nitrogen from the air into essential products for farmers and industrial customers. Through their environmental and industrial products, they help safeguard air and water quality and preserve food quality.Located in Norway, Yara International ASA is the world&#153;s leading chemical company that converts energy, natural minerals and nitrogen from the air into essential products for farmers and industrial customers. Through their environmental and industrial products, they help safeguard air and water quality and preserve food quality.Located in Norway, Yara International ASA is the world&#153;s leading chemical company that converts energy, natural minerals and nitrogen from the air into essential products for farmers and industrial customers. Through their environmental and industrial products, they help safeguard air and water quality and preserve food quality.Located in Norway, Yara International ASA is the world&#153;s leading chemical company that converts energy, natural minerals and nitrogen from the air into essential products for farmers and industrial customers. Through their environmental and industrial products, they help safeguard air and water quality and preserve food quality.Located in Norway, Yara International ASA is the world&#153;s leading chemical company that converts energy, natural minerals and nitrogen from the air into essential products for farmers and industrial customers. Through their environmental and industrial products, they help safeguard air and water quality and preserve food quality.Located in Norway, Yara International ASA is the world&#153;s leading chemical company that converts energy, natural minerals and nitrogen from the air into essential products for farmers and industrial customers. Through their environmental and industrial products, they help safeguard air and water quality and preserve food quality.Located in Norway, Yara International ASA is the world&#153;s leading chemical company that converts energy, natural minerals and nitrogen from the air into essential products for farmers and industrial customers. Through their environmental and industrial products, they help safeguard air and water quality and preserve food quality.</p>

            <p xmlns="" id="Client">
                <font color="#008000">
                    <strong>Customer</strong>
                </font>
            </p>
            <p xmlns="">
                <a href="http://www.yara.com/">Yara International ASA</a>Located in Norway, Yara International ASA is the world&#153;s leading chemical company that converts energy, natural minerals and nitrogen from the air into essential products for farmers and industrial customers. Through their environmental and industrial products, they help safeguard air and water quality and preserve food quality.Located in Norway, Yara International ASA is the world&#153;s leading chemical company that converts energy, natural minerals and nitrogen from the air into essential products for farmers and industrial customers. Through their environmental and industrial products, they help safeguard air and water quality and preserve food quality.Located in Norway, Yara International ASA is the world&#153;s leading chemical company that converts energy, natural minerals and nitrogen from the air into essential products for farmers and industrial customers. Through their environmental and industrial products, they help safeguard air and water quality and preserve food quality.Located in Norway, Yara International ASA is the world&#153;s leading chemical company that converts energy, natural minerals and nitrogen from the air into essential products for farmers and industrial customers. Through their environmental and industrial products, they help safeguard air and water quality and preserve food quality.Located in Norway, Yara International ASA is the world&#153;s leading chemical company that converts energy, natural minerals and nitrogen from the air into essential products for farmers and industrial customers. Through their environmental and industrial products, they help safeguard air and water quality and preserve food quality.Located in Norway, Yara International ASA is the world&#153;s leading chemical company that converts energy, natural minerals and nitrogen from the air into essential products for farmers and industrial customers. Through their environmental and industrial products, they help safeguard air and water quality and preserve food quality.Located in Norway, Yara International ASA is the world&#153;s leading chemical company that converts energy, natural minerals and nitrogen from the air into essential products for farmers and industrial customers. Through their environmental and industrial products, they help safeguard air and water quality and preserve food quality.Located in Norway, Yara International ASA is the world&#153;s leading chemical company that converts energy, natural minerals and nitrogen from the air into essential products for farmers and industrial customers. Through their environmental and industrial products, they help safeguard air and water quality and preserve food quality.Located in Norway, Yara International ASA is the world&#153;s leading chemical company that converts energy, natural minerals and nitrogen from the air into essential products for farmers and industrial customers. Through their environmental and industrial products, they help safeguard air and water quality and preserve food quality.Located in Norway, Yara International ASA is the world&#153;s leading chemical company that converts energy, natural minerals and nitrogen from the air into essential products for farmers and industrial customers. Through their environmental and industrial products, they help safeguard air and water quality and preserve food quality.
            </p>

            <p xmlns="" id="Overview">
                <strong>
                    <font color="#008000">Project Overview</font>
                </strong>
            </p>
            <p xmlns="">
                ITS Enterprise Services - security services will provide hosted and managed services as part of SO project for data center hosting and management. The security components include:</p>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</html>
```

I am sorry for all that long text, but it was required to show the issue I am facing.

Thanks in advance. 
Zeeshan

Answer (score 0):

This can not be achieved with pure HTML/CSS. You will need some kind of JavaScript.